# Javascript convert number string to Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, user-interface

I'm making this control toggle between `hide` and `show` base on the value in this hidden value. I wanted to use a Boolean because I can just do something like `== true`. Is this the best way to do this?
Working sample

https://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/4bdrfgcu/12/

```
    $("#hdMeetingDateId").val(500);
      //"#hdMeetingDateId").val(0);
      console.log($("#hdMeetingDateId").val());
                let hasMeetingDateId = $("#hdMeetingDateId").val() > '1' ;
      
      if (hasMeetingDateId == true) {
          $("#displayButton").hide();
      } else {
          $("#displayButton").show();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teepeemm is correct. It is best to avoid implicit [type coercions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) and use strict equality operators like [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) and [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality). The problem with loose comparisons (e.g. `==`, `!=`) is that it has [so many weird rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1575353) one would need to memorize in order to be confident in its proper usage.

Speaking of type coercion - it would be better to compare the value to the number one as a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead of a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

> ```
> let hasMeetingDateId = $("#hdMeetingDateId").val() > '1' ;
> ```

Since the less than and greater than operators will attempt to convert both operands to numbers<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description)</sup> it would be simpler to just represent it as `1`:

```
const hasMeetingDateId = $("#hdMeetingDateId").val() > 1 ;
```

And as was already mentioned jQuery's `toggle()` method can be used to simplify the conditionals. See this demonstrated in the snippet below. Note that the input was changed to an [`<input type=“number”>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). Also the DOM ready callback was simplified because as of jQuery 3.0, only `$(handler)` is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.<sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup>. Also the code makes use of the ES6 feature [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
$(_ => {  //jquery DOM ready callback with arrow function
    $('#hdMeetingDateId').change(function() { //change event handler
        const hasMeetingDateId = $(this).val() > 1;
        $("#displayButton").toggle(!hasMeetingDateId);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sample</h1>
  <input type="range" name="hdMeetingDateId" id="hdMeetingDateId" value="4" min="0" max="5" />

<p>
    <button id="displayButton">Value Button</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks what if I wanted to hide it for true?

Comment: Use the negated value: `$("#displayButton").toggle(!hasMeetingDateId)`

Answer (score 2):

As a general programming guide, you should avoid  `== true`, and just use `if ( hasMeetingId )`.  (Things are even worse in Javascript, because `==` behaves strangely, eg, `1==true` is true.  You should use `===` instead of `==` whenever possible.)

With Javascript, you could have `$("#displayButton")[hasMeetingDateId?"hide":"show"]()`, and it would collapse those five lines into one less comprehensible line.

But jQuery is a bit more helpful.  Instead of `hide` and `show`, you can use [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and end up with `$("#displayButton").toggle(hasMeetingDateId)`.

You should also use `const` instead of `let`, if you can.

Comment: What if I wanted to hide it for true?